# Form keeps creating new entries in my database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, date, datetime

I have a form called 'comment'. And i need to save the post date of my comment in the database, but using the php date() function, it keeps looping and entering the same entries over and over..

This is my code:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
if (isset($_POST['comment'])){
            $gepost = $date;
            $profiel = $_SESSION['profielID'];
            $comment = $_POST['comment'];
            $artikel = $_GET['id'];
            $query1 = "INSERT INTO comment (comment_profielID, comment_artikelID, comment_tekst, gepost) VALUES ('$profiel', '$artikel', '$comment', '$gepost')";
            $result = mysql_query($query1);
    }
```

Anyone got a solution?

Comment: There is no loop in your code

Comment: Why don't you use the MySQL `NOW()` function instead of the PHP `date()` function?

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) like the ones you have here. Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and is a safer way to compose queries. `$_POST` data **never** goes directly in a query.

Comment: Get your finger off the mouse button, or your ENTER key is stuck; there's no loop here. Maybe coffee found its way to your F5 key; who knows.

Comment: Echo $query1 post that result here